# How would today's world leaders react to aliens who claim to "come in peace"?

Tags: science-fiction, aliens

So we have finally received first contact from an alien civilization, a spaceship hovering in orbit around our world has broadcast a signal saying they "come in peace". Not only that, they seem to come bearing gifts of knowledge and advanced tech, offering to "teach us what we need to know to evolve". How would today's world leaders respond? Would they trust the messages and take a chance? Would the aliens be met with paranoia and mistrust? Would we simply ignore it altogether? A "see no evil hear no evil" attitude? Remember, all we know of them is the vague  messages and promises broadcast to us, and that they have interstellar ships and are extremely advanced. assuming this happened soon, in today's time and world, (anytime from tomorrow to about a year from now).

Comment: Probably would build a wall.

Comment: I think this is impossible to answer this question, because various country may react differently.

Comment: Impossible to tell. In general most world leaders are savvy politicians that treat all claims with cynicism requiring objective support before they are believed; they are not gullible OR trusting. Some are just sociopaths, megalomaniacs, or mentally ill freaks on a rampage that stumbled into power by a run of good luck because their opponents were just incompetent and unpopular enough to blow a sure thing.  So some few might embrace the aliens, or might believe the aliens are suckers and try to exploit them. Other such mentally unstable leaders would try to nuke them. This is opinion based.

Comment: Cross their fingers and hope the aliens are telling the truth.

Comment: It would be nice if any stack exchange user of the world gave an answer depending of what he think the officials of his own country would respond. It would give you a large panel of answers instead of one "universal answer" that doesn't exist.

Comment: For my part (I live in France), I guess we would welcome them as potential allies, broadcast a live encounter, sit around a table and discuss major points with a bunch of journalists, scientists, politics, maybe religious people. Then bureaucracy would kick in they'd have to file a lot of papers that would give them rights and duties while living in our borders. Under constant but discrete surveillance.

Comment: Are you considering the actions of only governmental world leaders of their countries, or to include the world leaders of other ideals and organizations, such as religious, spiritual, business/trade, security, enovironmentalists, scientists, entertainers, etc.?  Each of these types of leaders will respond differently within the context of their world views.  Specifying that aspect may help your question be considered less opinion based by allowing answering experts to consider current examples of similar responses for these different kinds of leaders.

Answer (score 1):

World leaders are not all of a mind. They will have different reactions.  I can suppose two common types of reaction, though:

Their existence contradicts religion, so denial or recasting in terms of the religion’s bad guys.

“How can I benefit from this to gain more power and influence?”

No world leader is rational in the sense of a scientist; they commonly see the world in terms of what they can convince people to accept without having any concept of objective truth.